# BMO1 2009/10 Problem 6

Tags: contest-math

Long John Silverman has captured a treasure map from Adam McBones. Adam has buried the treasure at the point $(x,y)$ with integer co-ordinates (not necessarily positive). He has indicated on the map the values of $x^2 + y$ and $x + y^2$, and these numbers are distinct. Prove that Long John has to dig only in one place to find the treasure.

Thanks in advance for any contributions.

Comment: @Casteels Apparantly yes. https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100627164855AAvBmLe

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lets we have two places to dig:
$$x_1^2 + y_1 = x_2^2 + y_2 \space (1)$$ and $$ x_1 + y^2_1 = x_2 + y^2_2 \space (2)$$
Rewrite equations as: $$\frac{x_1 - x_2}{y_2 - y_1} = \frac{1}{x_1 + x_2} $$ and 
$$\frac{x_1 - x_2}{y_2 - y_1} = y_2 + y_1$$
Because $y_2 + y_1$ is integer we conclude that $|x_1+x_2| = 1$ ;  $|y_1 + y_2| = 1$

Then consider separate cases when $x_1+x_2 = 1$ and $x_1+x_2 = -1$
Plugging each case into equation (1) and (2) we will see that $$x_1^2 + y_1 = x_1 + y^2_1$$ that is contradiction.

Interesting point here is that we cannot find numbers, only proof that they are unique.

Comment: I am not sure I understand why your last equation would follow by plugging in each case to (1) and (2). Would you mind helping me understand that part?

Comment: Let $x_1 = x, y_1 = y$, then (first case) $x_2 = 1 - x, y_2 = 1 - y$. Solving (1), (2) we will get that $y_1 = 1 - x$ and Adam's number are the same.

Comment: Thank you for elaborating on that!